# Как проверить значения в массиве в CGridView?

Tags: php, yii

Я формирую массив для `GridView` сам. Необходимо проверить значения на соответствие диапазону.

Предположим, функция мне возвращает данные в виде значения `1` или `0` в зависимости от наличия ошибки:

```
$val = 'num($data->id)[0]'; 
$myarray[] = array(
    'header' => $rows[$i2]['name'], 
    'type' => 'raw',
    'id' => $id,
    'value' => $val,
    'htmlOptions' => ('num($data->id)[1]' == 1) ?
            array('style' => 'width: 15px; text-align:center; background:#FFA07A;') :
            array('style' => 'width: 15px; text-align:center;'),
    'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align:center'),
);
```

Но, как понимаю, я храню значение как строку и поэтому не могу получить значение.

Comment: вы не могли бы показать больше кода, что за массив передаете, что находится в $rows, откуда у вас $id, вашу num функцию. Если вы id формируете из вне, то почему не формируете сразу значение, и зачем вы в htmlOptions сравниваете строку с единицей?

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось при формировании значения сразу его проверять. Получилось что-то вроде:

```
if ($val > $max)
    return '<font color="red">' . $val . '</font>';
else
    return $val;
```

Comment: решение наверно не лучшее, но ответом оно является